# Icon missing when we create the presentation of individual slide using OpenXMLPowerTools

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, openxml, add-in

We are working on a power point add-in application.  In this application we have a scenario to create individual slides of a presentation. We are using “OpenXMLPowerTools” to create individual slide presentation.

But the issue is, if the presentation having any icons , then  it seems that icons are missing, when we try to create the individual slides of the presentation.
 If anyone has any solution to guide us, please share. it would be helpful for us.

We are using PowerPoint 2016.

You can download the sample project from the following url.

http://122.166.23.155/iconsample